# To find the difference between two column elements in a data frame

Tags: r

My question is a very basic one and I am new to R and programming. I have a data frame `RESULT` with two columns `Max`, `Min` and 500 rows. I just want to find the difference between `Max` and `Min` and put the value in a third column `Difference`. I tried with the code:

```
select Max, Min, Max-Min as Difference from RESULT.
```

But I am getting

> Error: unexpected symbol in "select Max".

I also tried just with:

```
Difference<-c(RESULT$Max-RESULT$Min)
```

for which I am getting:

> Warning Message
>
> In Ops.factor(RESULT$Max, RESULT$Min) :
>         - not meaningful for factors

RESULT:

```
    Max Min
1   NaN NaN
2   25  NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN
6   25.6   23.1
```

I want to display `NaN` or any other variable like `X` or `Y` in `Difference` column whenever there is `NaN` in Either of `Max` or `Min`.    The output should be like:

```
    Max Min   Difference
1   NaN NaN   NaN
2   25  NaN   NaN
3   NaN NaN   NaN
4   NaN 34    NaN
5   NaN NaN   NaN
6   25.6   23.1   2.5
```

Comment: you should coerce your columns to numeric.

Comment: I understand that you're new to R but the answer to this question should have been very easy to Google and find out. I have answered this question but I would suggest that you look up what factors are, and why they are different from numeric datatypes.

Answer (score 15):

If `df` is your data.frame, `df$V3 <- df$V1 - df$V2` should add a new column called `V3` which is the difference of columns `V1` and `V2`.

Your error message says that the columns are factors. You can convert them to a numeric class by doing `df$V1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$V1))` and similarly for `V2`

Comment: Since you are new to R, I wanted to expand on why you need to convert to a character first.  In R, factors have two parts: an integer representing which level the value is and a vector of level labels.  Converting directly to numeric returns the integer level of each observation.  Converting the character returns the level label for each observation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to produce the desire output:

```
# Please import data as df.csv with given 2 columns name and respective data
setwd("D:\\Vishnu Jayswal\\Data_Science")
read.csv("df.csv")
View(df)
di <- ifelse(is.nan(df$Max) ==TRUE | is.nan(df$Min) ==TRUE,NaN,df$Max-df$Min)
di
df_final <- data.frame(df,di)
df_final
```

Comment: `is.nan(df$Max) ==TRUE | is.nan(df$Min) ==TRUE` can be shortened to `is.nan(df$Max) | is.nan(df$Min)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `sqldf` package which perform SQL Selects on R data frames.

```
RESULT <- sqldf("select MAX, MIN, (MAX - MIN) AS Difference from RESULT")
```

In this way you will have 3 columns `MAX`, `MIN` & `RESULT`.