# Find the difference between column elements

Tags: r

I am trying to find the differences between the column elements in R and I don't know how.

I have a data frame called `output9.bed` and I loaded in R by read.table command:

```
>read.table('output9.bed')
>v<-read.table('output9.bed')
> v
      V1        V2        V3
1  chr13  82264384  82264400
2  chr14  92493079  92493080
3  chr14  92493122  92493128
4  chr14  92493165  92493168
5  chr14 103491848 103491850
6   chr2 232576632 232576667
7  chr20  19393247  19393251
8  chr20  49582060  49582062
9   chr1  68299126  68299129
10 chr14  92493146  92493155
11  chr5 118309754 118309757
12  chr9 125667602 125667609
13  chr7 128045992 128046003
14  chr2 225450098 225450106
15  chr2 232325456 232325459
16  chr2 232325485 232325486
```

And I want to create a new column next to V3, which has the numerical differences between the numbers of V3 and V2. 
So, the output that I need should look like this :

```
> v

     V1        V2        V3     V4
1  chr13  82264384  82264400   17
2  chr14  92493079  92493080    2
3  chr14  92493122  92493128    7
4  chr14  92493165  92493168    4
5  chr14 103491848 103491850    3
6   chr2 232576632 232576667   36
7  chr20  19393247  19393251    5
8  chr20  49582060  49582062    3
9   chr1  68299126  68299129    4
10 chr14  92493146  92493155    10
11  chr5 118309754 118309757    4
12  chr9 125667602 125667609    8
13  chr7 128045992 128046003    12    
14  chr2 225450098 225450106    9
15  chr2 232325456 232325459    4
16  chr2 232325485 232325486    2
```

If you can help, it would be so nice.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838860/to-find-the-difference-between-two-column-elements-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
v$V3-v$V2+1
```

which is simple algebra.

Comment: I couldnt fix the columns, so '$' is the one. Thanks!